# How to update BIOS of Asrock H67M motherboard?

Tags: updates, bios

The problem is that I need to boot from a Live USB, but the motherboard does not recognize the USB, and the methods to enter BIOS set up (pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>DEL</kbd>) do not work at all. So I guess the BIOS should have been corrupted.  On the other hand, the BIOS is written for Windows. So I really feel being trapped and appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to reset you BIOS using the jumper on the motherboard, its jumper marked **CRLCMOS1** in the PCB.

Flip it 1 position wait 10 seconds and set it back to the previous position.

After that the [update method](http://www.asrock.com/support/BIOSUI.asp?cat=BIOS) should work, if not you should assume that your motherboard is really defect.

Comment: Thanks. I followed the instructions but still got blank page on the monitor. Assuming my MB is defected, what can I do now? I mean, are there "Ubuntu-friendly" MBs out there?

Comment: All of them are (mostly), your is just not because you cant enter your BIOS, if you needed to boot windows from a usb you would still be stuck. Really dont see it as a linux / windows problem. If you can configure it you can run it, if your stuck with a problem thats another issue :(

Comment: btw F10 and F12 normally allow you to choose which device to use for booting, try pressing them during post (press a lot of times every 1 sec, sometimes takes a bit for the option to set in). If you find anything else drop a comment. gl

Comment: try also F11, its reported to be the correct button.

Answer (score 0):

Run a copy of plop boot manager off a cd and then select the connected usb stick with the bios update within plop. It should then boot off the usb stick. Plop is a great work around for motherboards that don't support usb device booting.

http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager.html

Answer (score 0):

I have a Asrock H67M MB on my desktop. To get in to select bootdevice I have to press F11 during startup.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a software called `flashrom` in the repository that can be used to flash many motherboards and other devices.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/flashrom

If DOS is required in order to run any vendor-supplied flash utilities, then there is [FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org/).